# How to create custom drush command in 8.7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

I just tried this tutorial and it's not working. Could anybody knows or can find a drupal 8 drush 9 custom command tutotial or something? Please!

https://www.droptica.com/blog/creating-custom-drush-9-commands-drupal-8/

Comment: Hi, you didn't mention what version of Drush you are using, If you are doing Drupal 8 you should really be using Drush 9, perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Drush commands live in src/Commands nowadays. You are following an outdated tutorial.

Comment: Oh! They upgrade the to Drush 9.7.2... I was struggling with for 2 hours... I really forget that the Drush also came with version. Thanks for that notice!